# Law of total expectation applied to conditional mutual information?

Tags: conditional-probability, information-theory, mutual-information

I came across a book where the author uses the following property of mutual information:

Let $X$,$Y$,$Z$ be arbitrary discrete random variables and let $W$ be an indicator random variable.

$$
(1)\ \ I[ X : Y \mid Z ] 
  = Pr(W=0) I[ X : Y \mid Z, W=0 ] 
  + Pr(W=1) I[ X : Y \mid Z, W=1 ]\ 
$$

I don't understand why this property holds in general. 
To show this I was thinking to proceed as follows:
\begin{align}
I[ X : Y \mid Z ] 
  &= E_z[ I[ X : Y \mid Z = z ]] \\
  &= E_w[ E_z[ I[ X: Y \mid Z = z]\ |\ W=w ] ] \\
  &= Pr(W=0)E_z[ I[ X: Y \mid Z = z]\ |\ W=0 ] \\
  &+ Pr(W=1)E_z[ I[ X: Y \mid Z = z]\ |\ W=1 ].
\end{align}
where the second line follows by the law of total expectation. 
However, this does not seem to be the right approach since it's not clear to me that 
$$
E_z[ I[ X: Y \mid Z = z]\ |\ W=w ] = I[ X : Y \mid Z, W=w ]$$
holds.

What is the right way to show  (1)?

Comment: can you share the source and page/slide number?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/120782/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3547730/14578, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/449771/2921.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is cross-posted to multiple websites with positive engagement elsewhere.